# having spring integration tcpserver to manage clients and send them messages

Tags: java, tcp, spring-integration

I have already created a simple tcp server with spring integration which keeps a connection alive and responses to each request during the connection.

In that requestMethod, I'm also able to read the MessageHeder to get the connectionId.

Now I want to send messages from the server to the client.

As far as i understood the documentation i need to put the connectionid in the MessageHeader and then send the message. But I can't figure out how to do the latter one. I have the Message ready but how do i send/push it out?

Here is my xml-configuration:

```
<bean id="lfSerializer" class="org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.serializer.ByteArrayLfSerializer"/>

<int-ip:tcp-connection-factory
    id="socketserver"
    type="server"
    port="30124"
    using-nio="true"
    deserializer="lfSerializer"
    serializer="lfSerializer"
    single-use="false"/>

<int-ip:tcp-inbound-channel-adapter id="inboundServer"
    channel="inputChannel"
    connection-factory="socketserver"/>

<int-ip:tcp-outbound-channel-adapter id="outboundServer"
    channel="outputChannel"
    connection-factory="socketserver"
    />

<int:channel id="inputChannel">
    <int:interceptors>
        <int:wire-tap channel="logger"/>
    </int:interceptors>
</int:channel>

<int:channel id="outputChannel">
    <int:interceptors>
        <int:wire-tap channel="logger"/>
    </int:interceptors>
</int:channel>

<int:logging-channel-adapter id="logger" level="DEBUG" log-full-message="true"/>

<int:service-activator input-channel="inputChannel"
                   output-channel="outputChannel"
                   ref="echoService"
                   method="test"/>

<bean id="echoService"
    class="com.examples.EchoService" />
```

I also tried to create a bean and another serviceactivator for output, then autowired that bean and called it's "send" method, but I don't know what to implement in that send-method to send out a message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a simple request/response scenario use an inbound gateway instead of channel adapters and the framework will take care of the correlation for you. This is used in [the sample app](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/tcp-client-server). Simply have your POJO method return the reply payload.

If you want to send arbitrary messages to the client (i.e. NOT request/reply but, say, in, out, out, in, out, out, out etc) then, yes, you need to build the messages yourself, inserting the `ip_connectionId` header.

To send them, there are several options:

Inject `outputChannel` into your code

```
@Autowired
private MessageChannel outputChannel;
```

Use a `MessagingTemplate` to send to the channel (or simply call its `send(Message<?> message)` method directly).

Or

Use a [MessagingGateway](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#gateway) with a void return method and inject the gateway into your code.

**EDIT:**

Note, that if you want to start sending messages before receiving anything, you can obtain the connection id via the [connection opened event](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ip.html#tcp-events).

Comment: Autowiring the channel was what i missed. Thanks. :)